# PHP DOM Manipulation

Tags: php, html, xml, dom

I have a template in my DB with a styling, created by the user. Because users are generally stupid and also I don't want them to meddle with php code, I want to insert the actual values into their style before the template is rendered. It's dynamic values.

So I have things like

```
<p>Here is your value:</p>
<span id="value"></span>
<p>Enjoy it!</p>
```

A placeholder for the value. This is probably the easiest way. I can't/don't want use jQuery here, but I want something similar.

I've seen PHP's DOMDocument class, which seems to do the trick, with one problem: `$dom->saveHTML()` seems to be always saving the entire HTML tree. `$dom->saveHTML($element)` saves just that element, but I have several at once in my template.

Is there a trick to get them all saved without the html stuff around?

Comment: I can't say I understand the problem here... Mind if you explain it better? Do you need to save multiple elements without the HTML between them?

Comment: So you only need the inner HTML of the body tag/element?

Comment: I only need the bare HTML of my template.

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to build a templating engine. Why not use one of smarty.net, twig-project.org, phptal.org, etc?

Comment: Because I have just two tags with a special id to replace and no control over additional libs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`saveHTML()` saves the element itself and all its children.

You can save the body node to save the whole document content:

```
$body = $doc->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0);
$html = $doc->saveHTML($body);

// and remove <body></body>
$html = substr($html, strlen('<body>'), -strlen('</body>'));
```

Or save body's children one by one:

```
$html = '';
foreach($body->childNodes as $node) {
    $html .= $doc->saveHTML($node);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use libxslt's [XSLTProc](http://php.net/class.xsltprocessor)

```
$html = <<<HTML
<p>Here is your value:</p>
<span id='value'></span>
<p>Enjoy it!</p>
HTML;

$xslt = <<<XSL
<xsl:stylesheet version='1.0' xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform'>

<xsl:output encoding='UTF-8' method='html'/>

<xsl:template match='/html/body/*'>
    <xsl:copy-of select='.'/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
XSL;

$htmldoc = new DOMDocument();
$htmldoc->loadHTML($html);
$xsltdoc = new DOMDocument();
$xsltdoc->loadXML($xslt);

$xsltproc = new XSLTProcessor();
$xsltproc->importStylesheet($xsltdoc);
print $xsltproc->transformToXML($htmldoc);
```

Output:

```
<p>Here is your value:</p>
<span id='value'></span>
<p>Enjoy it!</p>
```